# Создать объект вложенной структуры Си

Tags: c, указатели, структуры

Есть две структуры для двоичного дерева поиска

```
typedef struct _price {
    double price;
    char* shopname;
} pricing;

typedef struct _bstnode {
    int id;
    pricing** pl;
    int nr_of_prices;
    struct _bstnode *left;
    struct _bstnode *right;
    struct _bstnode *parent;
} bstnode;
```

Есть функция которая добавляет в узел название магазина и цену, для одного узла может быть несколько, названий и цен
подскажите как это реализовать

```
void updatePrice(bstnode* root, int id, char* shop, double price){
//to do
}
```

Конкретно одно название магазина и цену я могу добавить

```
bstnode* root;    
(*(root->pl))=malloc(sizeof (pricing));
(*(root->pl))->price=price;
(*(root->pl))->shopname=shop;
```

А как сделать чтобы этих магазинов и цен внутри одного узла было сколь угодное количество, и как их потом редактировать или удалять из памяти?

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов реализации, может быть много. Один из вариантов сделать список.

```
typedef struct _price {
  double price;
  char* shopname;
} pricing;

typedef struct _list_prices list_prices; 
struct _list_prices
{
 pricing * pl;
 pricing * next;
};

typedef struct _bstnode {
  int id;
  list_price * begin_list;
  int nr_of_prices;
  struct _bstnode *left;
  struct _bstnode *right;
  struct _bstnode *parent;
} bstnode;
```

Но можно воспользоватся существующими реализациями [списоков, деревьев и т.д](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.48/)